# Webi schedule export csv to outlook

Tags: webi

I am new to business objects.  I created a report in Webi and then created a daily job to send the report as a csv data file attachment to my outlook inbox.  My question is... Will Webi automatically refresh with latest data before it send each day?

Comment: It depends on the logic on your report. When you refresh it in WebI do you always get the latest data? If so, then that is what will be sent in the email.

Comment: I was told the universe raw data is almost live, i created the report with daily autosend, therefore i expect the report received in outlook each day would be automatically refreshed with new data without requiring me to go into Webi to manually refresh each day, otherwise there is no point scheduling an autosend, isn't it

Comment: What is your criteria in the query? All I am getting at is that if today you had a date hard-coded that same hard-coded date would be in the version the scheduler runs. Can you edit the question and add a screenshot of your query?

Comment: The query does not have any date criteria, i pull everything only based on organization manager hierarchy. Also i am hoping to export the raw data in csv form to feed a PBI report, so it is critical the csv export each day does contain the refreshed latest data. This is what i want to validate

Comment: i'm having the same issue, the report is not updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will contain the latest data. You can validate this by just trying it out.

Comment: thanks, it worked out.  as the actual data is not changing a lot, have to wait for a while before I can see the actual changes.  now it's exporting daily from BO to a csv file emailed to my inbox and then shoot over to a SP folder where my PBI report gets new data from it.